# Xamarin Forms - Get path of embedded file

Tags: path, xamarin.forms, gif

I'm trying from hours/days to get a file which is placed into the PCL part

[image]

I saw some examples which using `BaseURL` but I want to make something cross platform and I can't found how to implement it onto UWP..

So I'm trying to get my local file's URL. For Images, I'm using `ImageSource.FromResource("Gif.example.gif")` but it doesn't work..

I also tried `GifSource = new Uri(ImageSource.FromResource("Gif.example.gif").ToString());` but.. Nothing !

There is my custom control:

```
public class Gif : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty GifSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Uri), typeof(string), typeof(Gif), null);
    public string GifSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(GifSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GifSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    Action<string> action;
    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

Thank for help !

Answer (score 0):

To get the image from the PCL-project you must use the full path (with the namespace) to the image.

In your case: `var src = ImageSource.FromResource("GifProject.Gif.example.gif");`

And be sure that the "Build Action" of your file is set to "Embedded Resource".

You can extend this with reflection, when you don't want to provide the namespace directly.

You can find more infos on how to deal with embedded images on the [xamarin developer page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images).